# How can I load a ResourceBundle from my resources build path?

Tags: java, gradle, resourcebundle

I have a folder containing some .properties files that I want to load into ResourceBundle. In my code, I try to pass the path of the resource folder. However, this doesn't work since the resources are in another build path. To clarify, I have two "source sets" one is called java and another called resources. It does work if I move the resources into the main source folder. However, it would make more sense if I can keep the resources in the resources folder and load them with ResourceBundle.getBundle() but I haven't been able to make it work. I think I need to include the resources folder in the classpath for the project but I'm just guessing. This seems like it would be a common use case, can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) from java or whatever 'ClassLoader' you are using.

Sample code

```
File file = new File("C:\\path\\myfile.ext");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("english", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```